# Craps Program - Does not seem to run the way I intended it to

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program where the user rolls two dice and gets a `7` or an `11` as the sum they automatically WIN, and play is over. A `2, 3`, or `12` automatically LOSES, and play is over. If a `4, 5, 6, 8, 9`, or `10` are rolled on this first roll, that number becomes the "Point" and play continues. But when I run it, it keeps running pause and the rolling is a bit messed up, no idea how to fix it.

```py
import random

def diceRoll():
    dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
    total = dice1 + dice2
    return total
def main():
    play_game = input("Would you like to play the game of Craps? (Y/n)")
    while (play_game[0].lower() != "n"):
    
        pause = input("Press <Enter> to roll the dice!")
        totalRoll = diceRoll()
        
        if totalRoll in (7, 11):
            result = "congratulations you won"

        elif totalRoll in (2, 3, 12):
            result = "you lost, try again next time"
    
        else:
            result = "continue your game please"
            currentpoint = totalRoll
            print("Good game " + " your current point is " + str(currentpoint))
           
        while result == "continue your game please":
            totalRoll = diceRoll()
    
            if totalRoll == currentpoint:
                result = "congratulations you won"
        
            elif totalRoll == 7:
                result = "you lost, try again next time"

    if result == "congratulations you won":
        print("congratulations, you won")
    else:
        print("you lost, try again next time")
main()
```

Comment: You have a loop whose termination is based on the value of variable `play_game`. Inside the loop, the value of that variable is never modified, and there are no other ways to exit the loop. That is an infinite loop.

Comment: Do you want the player to press Enter every time the dice are rolled?  Or just once at the start of the game?

Comment: Just to roll the dice. After the game starts.

Comment: Wait hold on I mean like, when the game starts, they press enter to roll and yeah like that.

Comment: Then you should probably move the `input()` statement to be inside the `diceRoll()` function.  Otherwise that function will roll the dice and return the total without the player even knowing they rolled.  You also might want to add a `print()` at the end of that function to tell the player what they rolled.

Answer (score 1):

I think the control flow got a bit confused here, so I've separated out the "play" idea into its own function, just for better readability.

Additionally, putting long strings like yours into global variables is a good practice, because it's easy to miss a comma or what not.

```py
import random

begin_prompt = "Would you like to play the game of Craps? (Y/n)"
dice_prompt = "Press <Enter> to roll the dice!"
win_message = "congratulations, you won"
lose_message = "you lost, try again next time"
continue_message = "continue your game please"

def diceRoll():
    dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
    total = dice1 + dice2
    print(f"Rolled {dice1} and {dice2} for a total of {total}")
    return total

def run_play():
    input(dice_prompt) # pause

    totalRoll = diceRoll()
    
    if totalRoll in (7, 11):
        result = win_message

    elif totalRoll in (2, 3, 12):
        result = lose_message

    else:
        result = continue_message
        currentpoint = totalRoll
        print(f"Good game your current point is {currentpoint}")
        
    while result == continue_message:
        totalRoll = diceRoll()

        if totalRoll == currentpoint:
            result = win_message
    
        elif totalRoll == 7:
            result = lose_message
    print(result)

def main():
    play_game = input(begin_prompt)
    while (play_game[0].lower() != "n"):
        run_play()
        play_game = input(begin_prompt)
        

main()
```

Comment: Um I don't know what those f" mean. I'm still new to python.

Comment: @Emily Those are formatted string literals, aka f-strings. They are super useful for printing the value of variables inside a sentence; the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) is a good read.

Comment: So, when they get a 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, or 10 on the first roll, that number becomes the "Point" and play continues.  Is there a way to include that?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some `break` statements in your code. This is commonly done to escape out of loops. Notice I also summed the second roll to the first roll.

```
import random

def diceRoll():
    dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
    total = dice1 + dice2
    return total
    
def main():
    play_game = input("Would you like to play the game of Craps? (Y/n)")
    while (play_game[0].lower() != "n"):
    
        pause = input("Press <Enter> to roll the dice!")
        totalRoll = diceRoll()
        
        if totalRoll in (7, 11):
            result = "congratulations you won"
            break

        elif totalRoll in (2, 3, 12):
            result = "you lost, try again next time"
            break
    
        else:
            result = "continue your game please"
            currentpoint = totalRoll
            print("Good game " + " your current point is " + str(currentpoint))
            break
           
        while result == "continue your game please":
            totalRoll += diceRoll()
    
            if totalRoll == currentpoint:
                result = "congratulations you won"
        
            elif totalRoll == 7:
                result = "you lost, try again next time"

        break

    if result == "congratulations you won":
        print("congratulations, you won")
    else:
        print("you lost, try again next time")
main()
```

Not totally sure if this is what you wanted. You could probably clean this up further in a myriad of ways (like the outer while loop condition can never be False once it is set to True).

Comment: So If a 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, or 10 are rolled on this first roll, that number becomes the "Point" and play continues. But it doesn't do that